# Moodle Scorm Resume from last slide

Tags: moodle, scorm, scorm1.2

I am using Moodle to open SCORM course but I am unable to resume it when the user visit next time. This is what I am doing.

When the Course is loaded in LMS this code runs.

```
var completionStatus = Getvalue("cmi.core.lesson_status");
            if (completionStatus == "not attempted") {
                SetValue("cmi.core.lesson_status", "incomplete");
            }
            SetValue("cmi.core.exit", "suspend");
            console.log(Getvalue("cmi.core.student_id"));
            console.log(Getvalue("cmi.core.student_name"));
            var entry = Getvalue("cmi.core.entry")
            console.log(entry);
            if (entry == "resume") {
                var val = Getvalue("cmi.suspend_data");
                SetValue("cmi.suspend_data", val);
            }
            else {
                SetValue("cmi.suspend_data", "8899657");
            }
            loadCoure(frameid, 0)
```

It works fine for the first time let say user leave the course at slide number 10 and hen again comes back the course is not resume.

Comment: Are you saving the cmi.suspend_data value each time the student navigates to a new location? If so, are you making a commit call after it?

Comment: this is the main issue. I am using Moodle to import Scorm Package but some how I am unable to get suspend_data its always empty although Lms initialize is called

Comment: I use other players like Reload Scorm player it seems they have control over Course. But I am not getting any control in my course

Comment: How shall I get a notification that user click next slide button?

Comment: I'm not clear about your question. If you are building a SCORM course, then your code is responsible for setting the cmi.suspend_data value when exiting, then retrieving it later when initializing a new session. SCORM doesn't control your course... it just provides an API to allow to you save and retrieve data. Also you should use cmi.core.lesson_location to save your student's location.

Comment: actually, I am using iSpring presenter to generate Scorm course. Then I create dispatch file like Scorm Cloud does if you are aware of it. The I import that dispatch file into moodle LMS and launch it.  My Api is initialized successfully. But I am unable to receive any suspend data it alwasy empty. but user name etc are available.

Comment: But If I follow the same step for Scorm Cloud dispatch I have no problem everything works great

Comment: Well, then this is really a question about iSpring I think. It looks like that tool can export a SCORM package on its own, so you should be able to import that straight to Moodle without using the dispatch file.  Also which version SCORM package are you exporting? I don't think Moodle has full support for 2004.

Comment: I am using Scorm 1.2 But Why the same course hosted in Scorm cloud and download dispatch is working in moodle while I created my own dispatch which is not working in Moodle?

Comment: can you tell me If i create the Scorm course using iSpring presenter Do I need a Scorm player to run this?

Comment: so the line that Gets the suspend_data, and then sets it right after is un-needed.  If This is iSpring code thats a odd one.  I don't see a LMSCommit() call anywhere in the sample, and that would be required to actually store / save the values being set.  Is it possible your trying to run SCORM 2004 vs 1.2?  I don't know how the SCORM Cloud dispatch works but we'd need to check if this is still SCORM 1.2 to SCORM 1.2 regardless.

Comment: Thats is the problem I am calling commit as well while the popup window is closed but I am not getting suspended data. I don't understand why this happening. Except for dispatch file If I upload the whole course in Scorm cloud it works fine.

Comment: One thing is not clear If I am creating Scorm Course using iSpring presenter do I need a Scorm Player to run this as well.While I see a player  when iSpreing presenter create scorm course

Comment: I've never used iSpring, but it looks like it can export SCORM 1.2 packages. You should import the SCORM 1.2 package into Moodle - it should provide the SCORM API / SCORM player that you need.